# Background colors not touching from two lines of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just trying to get the backgrounds touching on their long edge; like in this code, but with the two blues touching.

the code i have:

```css
.header h1{ background:#0060D3; padding:10px; text-align:center}
.header h3{ background:#00CBFF; padding:10px; text-align:center}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h1>Page Name!</h1>
 <h3>Subheading!</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to normalize the css (overwrite the default states of `padding` and `margin` properties).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header h1 {
  background: #0060D3;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center
}

.header h3 {
  background: #00CBFF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Page Name!</h1>
  <h3>Subheading!</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just one question, what exactly is the asterisks (*) for? Is it a class name for the whole document?

Comment: @CharlieTurner `*` stands for anything. It basically selects all elements.

Answer (score 0):

As much as Kind User's answer solves your problem perfectly, you will still find yourself having to ask for help again next time a similar problem occurs. So rather than attempt to answer your question directly, I will explain how to figure it out for yourself.

Your browser will have an inspector (usually right click and choose Inspect from the context menu). I often use Firebug which is an extended inspector you can install as a plugin, but it is not essential for this task and the one built into your browser will suffice.

Click on the button on the top left of the inspector that looks like a cursor over a box, then click on any element on your screen to select it.

You will see under 'rules' all of the CSS rules that are currently affecting that element. Selecting the 'box model' tab will allow you to see the size of the element itself as well as the padding, border and margin on each side. Hovering your cursor over the element will also highlight each part of the box model separately so you can easily tell that the white space you saw was part of the margin.

To test this theory, you could go back to the rules tab and create a new rule stating `margin:0px;` and you will immediately see the effects. This is an effective technique for checking what CSS changes would appear to do before adjusting your actual file.

[image]

Side note: Just for clarification, although I would like to think it was obvious, I never make such assumptions. Any changes made in the inspector are entirely non-persistent in that they will not be saved in your file. If you refresh the page it will reload from the file and any changes made in the inspector will be gone.